# Free Barcode API for .NET

Tags: c#, api, components, barcode

Is there a decent free API/component for printing barcodes in C#?

Comment: See similar question that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998209/how-to-generate-barcode-from-a-string-using-c

Comment: now, you can use ZXing library, it is on apache 2 license. https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/COPYING free to use in commercial app

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Could the [Barcode Rendering Framework](https://github.com/ScoreBig/barcoderender) at <strike>Codeplex</strike> GitHub be of help?

Comment: Hint - You need to download the source file in order to find some sample projects that show some examples.  There doesn't appear to be anything on the website.

Comment: Quick an easy "Hello World" c# sample:
Add Reference -> Browse -> Zen.Barcode.Core.dll.  
Then add in your code using Zen.Barcode
**Code39 Examples:**
`Code39BarcodeDraw barcode39 = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithoutChecksum;`
`pictureBox1.Image = barcode39.Draw("Hello World", 40);`

PitureBox1 will now display the barcode type 39.  It's readable by a scanner.

Comment: How to use this for a web application.?

Comment: Does it work with .net core?

Answer (score 52):

I do recommend [BarcodeLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeLibrary.aspx) (already removed from codeproject), but https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib looks like its copy on github.

Here is a small piece of code of how to use it.

```
        BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode()
        {
            IncludeLabel = true,
            Alignment = AlignmentPositions.CENTER,
            Width = 300,
            Height = 100,
            RotateFlipType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone,
            BackColor = Color.White,
            ForeColor = Color.Black,
        };

        Image img = barcode.Encode(TYPE.CODE128B, "123456789");
```

Answer (score 13):

There is a `"3 of 9"` control on CodeProject: [Barcode .NET Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/barcodectl.aspx)

Comment: This is very basic. Creates only ONE type of barcode.