# Barcode generation usingBarcode Rendering Framework in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I am using Barcode Rendering Framework for generating a barcode. I have downloaded their dll's. I can see,how it can be done in windows application. I want to do the same i.e, generating the barcode and using it in web application.
Following is the link for the question that can be used.
[Free Barcode API for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043341/free-barcode-api-for-net) and following is the code  :

```
Code39BarcodeDraw barcode39 = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithoutChecksum;
System.Drawing.Image img = barcode39.Draw("Hello World", 40);
pictureBox1.Image = barcode39.Draw("Hello World", 40);
```

How can I use the same functionality in web application?

Comment: Thanks for the edit help. Will take care next time.

Comment: I've put up together a Javascript [SVG Barcode](https://barcode.windegger.wtf/) generator. Maybe that helps you solve your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same code in ASP.NET, but you need to output the image via HTTP.

Say you have an ASP.NET web page that contains the following:

```
<IMG SRC="BarCode.aspx?par1=HelloWorld40OrWhatever" />
```

Then your `BarCode.aspx` page must generate and output the image:

```
Code39BarcodeDraw barcode39 = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithoutChecksum;
System.Drawing.Image img = barcode39.Draw("Hello World", 40);

Response.Clear();
Response.Type = "image/png";
img.Save(Response.OutputStream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: you need to fetch the bar code string from query string from part1. I found missing in the code.

Comment: @Roy Dictus : It worked. Now I want to print the barcode. Because I am making an inventory software. I need to take the print and stick it to the item. What I need to do to take its print.?