# generating a bar code using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, barcode, barcode-printing

Hi friends developers,

I'm stuck in these problem since many days, there is any developer here, who knew how to generates a bar code with vb.net, and if possible generat it as image.

Thanks

Comment: search google many codes avilable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free Barcode API for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043341/free-barcode-api-for-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [Free Barcode API for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043341/free-barcode-api-for-net), which i think can point you to many possible solutions