# How to generate a barcode in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, barcode, barcode-printing

Barcode being a string passed from the controller and displayed on the view:

```
@shelfEdge.Barcode
```

How do I get this to display in barcode format, just a matter of downloading a barcode font and adding it to the class?

any ideas welcome

**UPDATE**
Ive used the post in [Free Barcode API for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043341/free-barcode-api-for-net) from Andrei Schneider...

```
 BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode()
    {
        IncludeLabel = true,
        Alignment = AlignmentPositions.CENTER,
        Width = 300,
        Height = 100,
        RotateFlipType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone,
        BackColor = Color.White,
        ForeColor = Color.Black,
    };

    model.BarcodeImage = barcode.Encode(TYPE.CODE128B, "123456789");
```

then in view `@Model.BarcodeImage`

but this throws errro:

```
    Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Drawing.Image' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Source Error:




Line 54:                             </td>
Line 55:                             <td width="30%">
Line 56:                                 @Model.BarcodeImage
Line 57:                             </td>
Line 58:                         </tr>
```

and I have referenced system.drawing in project??

Comment: You need to use a third party component (ComponentOne, Aspose, etc)

Comment: Can you try with syncfusion bar code

Comment: thanks for the reply guys please see edit....whoever voted -1 please explain your reason?

Comment: I did not downvote, but you should not edit your question to add a new question. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the barcode as an image, and then render the image on the page as usual. See this free library:

http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/

Comment: @John did you read he new error? It is another question -and one fundamental. Runs down to "what the heck is an assembly and why do I need to add it to references if I want to use it?"

Comment: @John The error is self explanatory, simply add a reference to System.Drawing in your project and it will be gonne.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewBag.mostrar = "data:image/jpg;base64," +
 Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])model.BarcodeImage);
```

I hope than this help you