# ASP.NET "A generic error occurred in GDI+" only happens for PNG images on Vista machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+

I've been searching for a resolution to this vexing problem and found quite a few answers, which unfortunately don't seem to work for me.

I have the following ASP.NET code that should output an image to the web browser as either JPEG or PNG:

```
public partial class MyImg : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(880, 520))
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            try
            {
                gfx.Clear(Color.Aqua);
            //  finalizeOutput(bmp, gfx, MyImageType.SCGIT_JPEG);   //Works
                finalizeOutput(bmp, gfx, MyImageType.SCGIT_PNG);    //DOES NOT Work
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }

}
    protected void finalizeOutput(System.Drawing.Graphics gfx, Bitmap bmp, MyImageType imageType)
    {
        //Get image type
        ImageFormat imgFmt;
        string strContentType;
        switch (imageType)
        {
            case MyImageType.SCGIT_GIF:
                strContentType = "image/gif";
                imgFmt = ImageFormat.Gif;
                break;
            case MyImageType.SCGIT_PNG:
                strContentType = "image/png";
                imgFmt = ImageFormat.Png;
                break;
            default:
                strContentType = "image/jpeg";
                imgFmt = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                break;
        }

        //Finalizing and Cleaning Up 
        Response.ContentType = strContentType;
        bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, imgFmt);    //THROWS EXCEPTION for png type: "A generic error occurred in GDI+."
//      bmp.Dispose();
//      gfx.Dispose();
        Response.End();
    }

}
```

What happens is that the above method works flawlessly from my VS2010 development IIS installed on Windows 7, but when I try the exact same code on Vista, it throws the "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception, but only for the image type PNG, it works OK for JPEG.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Where are those `bmp` and `gfx` variables initialized? IDisposable resources such as bitmaps and graphics should be as short lived as possible and always wrapped in using blocks to avoid leaking handles and ensure proper disposal.

Comment: They are initialized in the Page_Load when I'm prepping the image. After that my finalizeOutput is called to put it out to the browser.

Comment: I would recommend you doing this in the same method and wrap the those IDisposable objects in using statements.

Comment: OK, I will. But how would that affect this exception?

Comment: Failing to properly dispose those resources could result in this exception.

Comment: OK, let me recode it quickly and we'll see if it changes anything... hang on...

Comment: OK. I just added 'using' blocks, rebooted this Vista system and, as I told you initially... the exception still comes up.

Comment: I just updated it in my post. What else do you want to see?

Comment: I want to see where you are instantiating those gfx and bmp variables. I didn't even notice you updated your post. I told you to use `using` statements. Not calling .Dispose manually.

Comment: OK, you're right. I didn't show it all. Just updated it to the exact way I call it. Note that disposing manually won't do any difference.

Comment: So can anyone else help me find a resolution to this?

Comment: Please read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629251/c-sharp-outputting-image-to-response-output-stream-giving-gdi-error