# output image using web api HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying the following code to output a image from a asp.net web api, but the response body length is always 0.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(@"path to image"));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

    return response;
}
```

Any tips?

WORKS:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Resize(string source, int width, int height)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

        // Photo.Resize is a static method to resize the image
        Image image = Photo.Resize(Image.FromFile(@"d:\path\" + source), width, height);

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());

        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure if I got you - but you could check [**how to write an image to outputStream**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629251/c-sharp-outputting-image-to-response-output-stream-giving-gdi-error)

Comment: I'm not receiving a error, I'm just receiving nothing at all.

Comment: what status code are you getting back?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you should update your example to properly dispose, just for noobs who might come along and copy/paste into their application.

Comment: How do we use the end points to display the image on a .net core web app? On a browser it seems to only need the endpoint itself to load the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The the following:

1. Ensure path is correct (duh)
2. Ensure your routing is correct. Either your Controller is ImageController or you have defined a custom route to support "GetImage" on some other controller.
   (You should get a 404 response for this.)
3. Ensure you open the stream:

   `var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);`

I tried something similar and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a ByteArrayContent you can also use a StreamContent class to work more efficient with streams.