# Return image url as result of web api 2 query

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api2

EDIT: 
I've update with a controller to get stream resources, but some how it still doesn't work

```
public class ResourcesController : Controller
{
    public string Directory = @"D:\Desktop\MusicDatabase\Image\";

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Image/{type}/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Image(string type, string id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var url = Path.Combine(Directory, type, id + ".jpg");
        byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(url);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileData);
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
        return httpResponseMessage;
    }     
}
```

It return a string, not the resoure file

[image]

When I debug, "url" variable is

```
"D:\\Desktop\\MusicDatabase\\Image\\song\\2.jpg"
```

---

old:

I have 2 project: 1 web api2 for the server, 1 WP8 app for the client.

the server contains db where I have link to external file resources

e.x a Song table with IMAGE column where I stored this picture in my Desktop

```
public partial class Song
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    private string _IMAGE;
    public string IMAGE 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Helper.Helper.ConcatDirectory(_IMAGE);
        }
        set
        {
            _IMAGE = value;
        }
    }
```

In my DB, I stored "IMAGE" column only by its index (like "Song\1.jpg"), then when I have some queries to sever, I return full URL by this

```
public class Helper
{
    public static string Directory = "D:\\Desktop\\MusicDatabase\\";
    public static string ConcatDirectory(string input)
    {
        return string.Concat(Directory, input);
    }
}
```

When I tried a query in web browser , this URL will return file stored in my PC

[image]

But my WP8 app can't show this image (debug with emulator).
While I don't want to store this resource in my project , so is there anyway to return these images here ? (Any diffirent file type later, like song, video ...)

Comment: `IMAGE` is a string, containing the path to the image. You can't just send that to the phone and have the image appear. You need to read the contents of the image file and send that binary data in the response.

Comment: Please have a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001588/output-image-using-web-api-httpresponsemessage. This is how you will be able to read the image from your phone.

Comment: @ParthShah : I've updated the question, still can't get it work, I'm quite newbie in server app

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
```

with

```
httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms);
```

---

EDIT:

I really think you should try to understand the following advise from other fellow SO users:

1) Handling static images in ASP.NET WebAPI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12559507/2310818.