# download a file only one time in vb.net and IIS

Tags: vb.net, security, hyperlink, iis-7.5

I have a link

> http://www.example.com/foldername/1.jpg

Is there a way to make this link usable ony once? In other words, if a user downloads this image and anyone tries to download it again (even the same user) the link will not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a VB.NET script that reads the image from a protected directory and outputs it to the response stream and then simply delete this image from the directory.

See **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629251/c-sharp-outputting-image-to-response-output-stream-giving-gdi-error)** how to write an image to the response stream.

Comment: Also use the POST method to retrieve the image, [`GET` should be a safe method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: is there a way without binding the link to a VB.NET project?

Comment: Please be more specific.