# In WPF how to give the InteropBitmap drawing font

Tags: c#, wpf

ex winform：

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newimg);
String str = "hello world";
Font font = new Font("Arial", 30);
SolidBrush sbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
g.DrawString(str, font, sbrush, new PointF(100, 120));
```

In the WPF on how the InteropBitmap to do the same thing?

Comment: Does the example work for you when running it in Winforms..? check this working example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphics object in Wpf is different than Winforms since Wpf uses Vector Graphics. In Wpf you will be using a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.formattedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the DrawingContext is equivalent to the Graphics object in Winforms. This is a quick example to show what I mean.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Grid myGrid = new Grid();
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\temp\test.jpg")); //Use the path to your Image 
    DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen();
    dc.DrawImage(bmp, new Rect(100, 100, 300, 300));

    dc.DrawText(new FormattedText("Hello World",
                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Arial"),
                30, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black),
                new System.Windows.Point(100, 120));

    dc.Close();

    myGrid.Background = new VisualBrush(dv); 
    this.Content = myGrid;
}
```