# PictureBox.Image is null when using a stylus

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to save the contents of a PictureBox to a database. This in itself works well, however once the signature picture box has been drawn on, it is not setting the PictureBox.Image property, meaning I can't continue with the process.

```
 Pen myPen;
    bool bMouseDown = false;
    Point prevPoint;
    Graphics gCust;
    Graphics gTech;

private void NewJob_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        gCust = pbCustomerSig.CreateGraphics();
        gCust.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        myPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
        myPen.SetLineCap(LineCap.Round, LineCap.Round, DashCap.Round);
        myPen.Color = Color.Blue;
        myPen.Width = 2f;
}
public static byte[] ImageToBinary(Image image)
    {
        Byte[] buffer = (Byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(image, typeof(Byte[]));
        return buffer;
    }
private void pbCustomerSig_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        prevPoint = e.Location;
        bMouseDown = true;
    }

    private void pbCustomerSig_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bMouseDown)
        {
            Point thisPoint = e.Location;
            if (prevPoint.X == 0 && prevPoint.Y == 0)
            {
                prevPoint = thisPoint;
                return;
            }
            gCust.DrawLine(myPen, thisPoint.X, thisPoint.Y, prevPoint.X, prevPoint.Y);
            prevPoint = thisPoint;
        }
    }

    private void pbCustomerSig_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bMouseDown = false;
    }
```

The error is here -

```
h.CustomerSignature = ImageToBinary(pbCustomerSig.Image);
```

Any ideas why the PictureBox.Image property is null?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not assign a value for `pbCustomerSig.Image`. It's normal to be null.
Instead of doing that try to draw into a bitmap.
[Here is a sample for drawing on existing bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap) but you can draw on a empty bitmap with same way and show it on picturebox at the same time.