# How to create an jpeg image in C#.NET and add text into it

Tags: c#

I am having a small project where in i have to create an image and insert formatted text into specific position in it.

Like I want to insert text [HELLO WORD] where HELLO WORLD should be BOLD,size-12px and it should have font as TIMES NEW ROMAN.

Please someone could help me with a small example so i can proceed further.

Thank you

Comment: JPEG or Bitmap anything is okay. I just need to create an image with formatted characters filled.

Comment: use the System.Drawing namespace. There you'll find the Graphics class which provides functions to draw on bitmaps.

Comment: Can i Add text into it ? i mean formatted text ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap