# Covert Text file to Tiff image

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to convert a part of a .txt file to TIFF image, as

```
public static void ReadTextFileLineByLine(string fileName)//fileName- "c:\\test.txt"
{
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        List<string> linelist = new List<string>();            
        System.IO.StreamReader file =  new System.IO.StreamReader(strFileName);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && counter!=19)
        {
            linelist.Add(line);
            counter++;
        }
        file.Close();
        ConvertlistToByteArrayToTiff(linelist);
    }

    public static void ConvertlistToByteArrayToTiff(List<string> list)
    {         
        byte[] dataAsBytes = list
          .SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))
          .ToArray();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dataAsBytes);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        returnImage.Save("c:\\133.tiff", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);        
    }
```

I am getting error at `Image.FromStream(ms);`:

> Parameter is not valid.

Is my approach correct or I need to do it in different way?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but MSDN says the method will throw an `ArgumentException` if "The stream does not have a valid image format". Do you get that in your code?

Comment: I am passing memorystream that i am getting from byte array, and in above code you can see, byte array is from string list that I am reading from plain text file - line by line. Do you have any other approach to achive the goal - Text file to TIFF image?

Comment: can you provide example of this "text file"?

Comment: Text file sample: A new welcome to Yahoo. 
The new Yahoo experience makes it easier to 
discover the news and information that you care about most. 
It's the web ordered for you

Answer (score 1):

> Is my approach correct

No

> or I need to do it in different way?

**Yes**

You can "print"/draw the text to an image. Like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311628/2655508

Your assumption, that a tiffs (or any other image) representation of text, is just the ascii value of the chars isn't correct.

To read about Tiff: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format

To understand the structure of Tiff: See [RFC 2306](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2306)