# Add custom image or text to QR code generated by ZXing.Net

Tags: c#, zxing, qr-code

I use [ZXing.Net](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com) library to generate a QR code image -

[image: app screenshot]

At the top of my class:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

My method:

```
    protected void UpdateQRSource(String address)
    {
        QRCodeWriter qrcode = new QRCodeWriter();
        BarcodeWriter barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new EncodingOptions
            {
                Width = 300,
                Height = 300,
                Margin = 4
            }
        };

        using (Bitmap bitmap = barcodeWriter.Write(address))
        {
            IntPtr hbmp = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            try
            {
                BitmapSource source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hbmp, 
                    IntPtr.Zero, 
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                qrImage.Source = source; // set WPF image source
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(hbmp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please advise me how to add short text string or a custom image in the middle of the QR code - similar to the [Wikipedia visual QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#/media/File:Extreme_QR_code_to_Wikipedia_mobile_page.png) below:

[image: Wikipedia]

**UPDATE:**

Embedding custom logo in QR code (without breaking the latter!) seems to be not a trivial task as the scientific publication [QR Images: Optimized Image Embedding in QR Codes](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/262527881_QR_Images_Optimized_Image_Embedding_in_QR_Codes) shows...

But I still wonder if I could generate a QR code (as in the above source code), then overlay it with a custom text or logo, then validate the resulting image again by ZXing.Net.

Comment: I don't know the libs but this is not text, this is an image, you should look in this direction

Comment: Yes, sure the final output is an image - but I am after any methods in ZXing library to add custom text or images inside of the generated QR. Also, I can not just put my image on top of the QR and then just hope it is still readable thanks to error correction (as some blogs suggest) - because my QR is dynamically generated and contains (variable) Bluetooth address + more stuff.

Comment: What I meant is that there is no method to add text, there is just a method to add image in your qrcode, like wikipedia put the wikipedia logo and not the text `wikipedia`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here we go (you can use any logo):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode.Internal;
using ZXing.Rendering;


namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private string imagePath = @"YourPath";
    private string url = @"https://en.WIKIPEDIA.ORG/";
    private int size = 400;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox1.Image = GenerateQR(size, size, url);
        pictureBox1.Height = size;
        pictureBox1.Width = size;
        Console.WriteLine(checkQR(new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image)));
    }

    public bool checkQR(Bitmap QrCode)
    {
        var reader = new BarcodeReader();
        var result = reader.Decode(QrCode);
        if (result == null)
            return false;
        return result.Text == url;
    }


    public Bitmap GenerateQR(int width, int height, string text)
    {
        var bw = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter();

        var encOptions = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            Margin = 0,
            PureBarcode = false
        };

        encOptions.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);

        bw.Renderer = new BitmapRenderer();
        bw.Options = encOptions;
        bw.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        Bitmap bm = bw.Write(text);
        Bitmap overlay = new Bitmap(imagePath);

        int deltaHeigth = bm.Height - overlay.Height;
        int deltaWidth = bm.Width - overlay.Width;

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        g.DrawImage(overlay, new Point(deltaWidth/2,deltaHeigth/2));

        return bm;
    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

And the output:

> True

Comment: It is great code, thanks (+1) but is missing the validation of the resulting bitmap... (i.e. if `bm` is still being a valid QR-code)

Comment: Wouldn't `return result.Text == url` throw an exception if decoding fails (I am C# newbie)? Shouldn't it better be written as `return result != null && result.Text == url`?

Comment: Isn't `result.Text == url` just comparing string addresses? Shouldn't you better call `url.Equals(result.Text)` to compare string contents?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber you [can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) but that's not an obligation for strings

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Whats the purpose of the "PureBarcode" property? In the documentation is says: " Don't put the content string into the output image." That's not very clear!

Comment: That's for barcode symbologies that have a human-readable text/number line below them, like EAN, UPC, Code 128, etc. It should not make any difference for symbologies that don't have that line, like most (or even all?) 2D barcodes.

Comment: In real-life code, don't forget to use `using` with your IDisposables (in particular, `Bitmap` and `Graphics`)!

Answer (score 2):

Since you get a bitmap out of ZXing you can use standard C# techniques to draw text. See this answer for more info:

[c# write text on bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap)

For posterity here's some shamelessly copied code:

```
Bitmap bmp = //from ZXing;

RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(70, 90, 90, 50);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.DrawString("yourText", new Font("Tahoma",8), Brushes.Black, rectf);

g.Flush();
```