# How i can generate QR code with logo on Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, qr-code, zxing, generate

I want to generate QR code with logo like this:

Environment: Unity3D C#

[image]

I try to write code by examples from Internet.

```cs
private Texture2D GenerateBarcode(string data, BarcodeFormat format, int width, int height)
{
        var encodeOptions = new EncodingOptions
        {
            Height = height,
            Width = width,
            Margin = 0,
            PureBarcode = false
        };
        encodeOptions.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);

        BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = encodeOptions
        };

        Color32[] pixels = writer.Write(text);
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height);
        tex.SetPixels32(pixels);
        tex.Apply();
        return tex;
}
```

Q1: How i can change fill color the QR code from black color to the green color?

Q2: How i can change "black squares" on the sides of the QR code  to another similiar figuare?
[image]

Please, help. I have no idea what i need did .

A1: Answer from **derHugo**

```
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++){
          var pixel = pixels[i];
                if (pixel.r == 0 && pixel.g == 0 && pixel.b == 0)
                {
                    pixel = Color.green;
                }
                else {
                    pixel = Color.white;
                }
                pixels[i] = pixel;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To question one: Simply iterate over the pixels and tint the black ones with green instead like

```c#
Color32[] pixels = writer.Write(text);

for(var i=0; i<pixels.Length; i++)
{
    var pixel = pixels[i];
    if(pixel.r == 0 && pixel.g == 0 && pixel.b == 0) continue;

    pixel = Color.black;
    pixels[i] = pixel;
}

Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height);
tex.SetPixels32(pixels);
tex.Apply();
```

---

To question 2: There are a lot of similar question out there like e.g. [Add custom image or text to QR code generated by ZXing.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053936/add-custom-image-or-text-to-qr-code-generated-by-zxing-net) or also [this post](https://aboullaite.me/generate-qrcode-with-logo-image-using-zxing) at least for the middle Logo. The principle for the edges would be basically the same: Overwrite according pixels with a custom image.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understod some about QR code. In QR code generation have "QR Code Error Correction Level" , which help read to QR code if we see just 70%. It's mean, I can put any picture 30% on QR code.