# how can I add jpg file or any type of image in qrcode using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext, qr-code

I have create a QRcode with iTextSharp but how can i add image in QRcode?

for example in my code:

```
var paramQR = new Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object>();
paramQR.Add(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
paramQR.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode("some text", 50, 50, paramQR);
```

I want replace `"some text"` with an image.
can i do that?

Comment: I think you will need a QR libary that supports image integration. Google should help you. Or do you mean you want the QR as an image? (Do go for jpg as it will be too soft.)  Any QR lib should be able to do that..

Comment: you can also encode a picture into base64 string and insert the string to the QR code 
e.x. "data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

Comment: @TaW No I want to insert an image inside qrcode. and unfortunately, I did not find anything I searched for.

Comment: @OrYaacov can you give me a sample? thanks a lot

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053936/add-custom-image-or-text-to-qr-code-generated-by-zxing-net) ? Or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgcHT6Uu_ew)

Comment: I want to let other people see the pictures by scanning the QR code

Comment: Huh? So what you really want is to have a link to the images in the QR code? Where shall they be stored? You can't encode images of any interesting site in the small amout of data the QR can hold!