# save a image as byte[] from graphic object in c#

Tags: c#, printing, arrays, system.drawing

I will get image in byte from database and using system.drawing.graphic to add some necessary stuff , and after this i need to save this image in byte[] and send to front end (silver light 4) to print.

note(I am not going to save this in physical file).

I appreciate every help or you guys and provide example code if possible.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv

Comment: this was just the conversion from byte > image > byte.
my problem is how to use system.drawstring to customize my stuff and convert it to byte[] and send to front end to print

Comment: I have no idea how can this work, previous i was doing all the system.drawstring inside the printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) event. now i am looking for move the function to back end and only return image to front end

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap should give you (or whoever want to provide complete copy-paste-ready answer) head start. If not enough info search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+draw+text+bitmap ...

Answer (score 7):

```
byte[] result;
using (Image newImage = new Bitmap(origImage))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        // do some drawing
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        result = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

To restore the image from the `byte[]`:

```
Image restored = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(result));
```