# how to add Name in listview imagelist c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Heres my code :

```
this.imageList1.Images.Add("Original",image);
this.imageList1.Images.Add("Greyscale",greyscale.ToBitmap());
for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = j;

            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

I want to give each image a name/tag so it will show something like this in list view  :

[image]

but the above code seems not working

Comment: What is type of Image? If you already set the name, you need to bind the field in your ListView DataItemTemplate.

Comment: That's not what that parameter is for. It's a key you can use later to look up the image in the ImageList. If you want to add text to the image itself, [this answer should help you get started with that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6311628/424129). If what you want to do is something other than that, please explain in more detail.

Comment: i mean i want to insert image from imagelist to listview and give each image a little name so it will be like the picture above

Comment: why are you assigning item.ImageIndex = j;?

Comment: Set the `item.Text` property.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks thats solve my problem