# How To Print High Quality Text in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Using Bitmap for Printing form in windows form.But Text quality is low.

How to Increase Printing Quality in Windows form?

Comment: How does that text end up on your bitmap? If you are adding your own text manually, perhaps this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap

Comment: To do this you want to draw the picture and the text separately in a subroutine that takes a graphics object as an input. Then, use a Panel to display the output on the display. Supply the subroutine with the Panel's Paint event graphics and the PrintPage event's graphics.

Comment: You normally need to grow longer arms to make screenshots look good on paper.  The difference between the resolution of a monitor and the resolution of the printer is too great.  A factor of 6, typically.  So every pixel in a letter shape turns into a 6x6 ink blob on paper.  Especially troublesome with the anti-aliasing techniques used to make text on the monitor more readable.  The red and blue tints that ClearType uses just don't work at all on paper.  No magic workarounds, but to make sure you don't enlarge the bitmap too much so short arms work.  And to use PrintDocument properly.