# How to add text below QR code using QRCoder in C#?

Tags: c#, qr-code

QRCoder: https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder

```
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("This is QR Code", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
```

How to add text below QR code in the above *qrCodeImage* image object, like the below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question should be approached as "How do I add text to a Bitmap?", and there are answers for it here: [c# write text on bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6311545/4088472)