# C# convert number to barcode and send to printer

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode-printing

As part of a project I need to convert a numer to a barcode, then send a list of those numbers (or barcodes depending when the conversion should be done) to a printer to be printed on small sticker labels.

So far I have the list I need, but 2 things I have never done before and would like poiners are:

How do you convert to a barcode, is there a plug-in, or can this be done within ASP.NET / C# without any 3rd party dll?

Once I have the make / model of the printer and the dimensions of the label, should I be looking for a plug-in for this, or try to create a template.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998209/how-to-generate-barcode-from-a-string-using-c) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750659/print-images-c-net)

Comment: Bar codes are fonts, you can download Code 39 font from here https://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/

Comment: excellent, just what I need, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate barcode from a string using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998209/how-to-generate-barcode-from-a-string-using-c)